# Entity that has two semantical types in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I need for an entity in my project to have two semantical types;
Assume `Post` entity that can be two type of post: "text" post & "link" post.
So my post entity is something like this:

```
Class Post{
    private $id;
    private $type;
    private $text=nul;
    private $link=null;

    ...
}
```

Now a post only can have one of `text` or `link` fields based on the `type` field and the other should be `Null`
How can I implement such a thing with Symfony2 / Doctrine / Forms ?
Should I split it to two entities or symfony can manage such a situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [inheritance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) in this case. Declare an abstract class with properties common to both `LinkPost` and `TextPost`:

```
@Entity
@InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="discriminator", type="string")
@DiscriminatorMap({"text"="TextPost", "link"="LinkPost"})
abstract class Post {
    @Id @GeneratedValue @Column
    private $id;

    @ManyToOne(...)
    private $author;
}

@Entity
class TextPost extends AbstractPost {
    @Column
    private $content;
}

@Entity
class LinkPost extends AbstractPost {
    @Column
    private $url;
}
```